# Test class and code coverage for FSL ServiceAppointment

Tags: apex, code-coverage, scheduled-apex, failing-tests, fsl

I have below class for which I am writing test class.

```
global class FSL_ScheduleSABatch implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

global List<ServiceAppointment> saToShedule = new List<ServiceAppointment>();

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    Datetime nMinsBack = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-15);
    String query = "SELECT Id, AccountId, Case__c, Case__r.Origin, Case__r.Category__c, WorkType.Name, 
    Work_Order__c, Work_Order__r.AccountId, Status FROM ServiceAppointment WHERE (CreatedDate >= :nMinsBack) 
    ORDER BY CreatedDate";
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<ServiceAppointment> saList) {
    Id schedulingPolicyId = [SELECT Id FROM FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c WHERE Name = 'Soft Boundaries'].Id;
    FSL.ScheduleResult scheduleResult = new FSL.ScheduleResult();     
    for (ServiceAppointment sa: saList) {  
        saToShedule.add(sa);
        scheduleResult = FSL.ScheduleService.schedule(schedulingPolicyId, sa.Id);
        
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    FSL_ScheduleSABatch saBatch = new FSL_ScheduleSABatch();
    Database.executeBatch(saBatch, 1);
}
```

}

Below is test class that I have written which covers around 70% code coverage.

```
@isTest
public class FSL_ScheduleSABatchTest {
    static testMethod void testschedule() {
        Test.StartTest();
        FSL_ScheduleSABatch testSASche = new FSL_ScheduleSABatch();
        String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?';
        system.schedule('Test status Check', sch, testSASche );
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    static testMethod void testschedule2() {
        Account accObj = new Account(Name ='TestAccount 007');
        insert accObj;
        
        Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Service_Case').getRecordTypeId();
        Case caseObj = new Case();
        caseObj.AccountId = accObj.id;
        caseObj.RecordtypeId = recordTypeId;
        caseObj.Status = 'New';
        caseObj.Subject = 'Test Case';
        insert caseObj;
        
        WorkType wt = new WorkType();
        wt.Name = 'EGM - Break Fix';
        wt.Categories__c = 'Breakfix';
        wt.Function__c = 'Service';
        insert wt;
        
        WorkOrder woObj = new WorkOrder();
        woObj.CaseId = caseObj.Id;
        woObj.AccountId = accObj.Id;
        woObj.WorkTypeId =  wt.Id;
        woObj.Status = 'New';
        insert woObj;
        
        ServiceAppointment sAppointment = new ServiceAppointment();
        sAppointment.ParentRecordId = woObj.Id;
        sAppointment.Status='New';
        Datetime nMinsBack = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-15);
        sAppointment.CreatedDate=nMinsBack;
        insert sAppointment;
        
        Test.StartTest();
        FSL_ScheduleSABatch ScheduleSABatchobj= new FSL_ScheduleSABatch();
        Id jobid= Database.executeBatch(ScheduleSABatchobj,1);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

I am not able to get code coverage for  below lines.

```
Id schedulingPolicyId = [SELECT Id FROM FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c WHERE Name ='Soft Boundaries' LIMIT 1].Id;
FSL.ScheduleResult scheduleResult = new FSL.ScheduleResult();     
    for (ServiceAppointment sa: saList) {  
        saToShedule.add(sa);
        scheduleResult = FSL.ScheduleService.schedule(schedulingPolicyId, sa.Id);

    }
```

Can anyone please help me to get 100% code coverage for lines ? Also, my test case fails for testschedule2 method saying that System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject on `Id schedulingPolicyId = [SELECT Id FROM FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c WHERE Name ='Soft Boundaries' LIMIT 1].Id;` line. I do have data for this row.

Comment: When you say you have data for this row, unless I missed it, I cannot see where you are inserting it in your test. Tests cannot see data on your org (except when you specifically request it, but for me this is something to avoid). A test needs to insert all necessary data if your tested code is directly querying data.

Comment: Thanks Phil for pointing it out. Now I am inserting data for FSL__Scheduling_Policy__c  in my test class and that List has no rows for assignment to SObject is not coming. However I am getting another error on this line 
scheduleResult = FSL.ScheduleService.schedule(schedulingPolicyId, sa.Id); 
It is sayiing FSL.Exceptions.GeneralException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.
(System Code)
Class.FSL_ScheduleSABatch : line 30, column 1
Caused by
(System Code)
Class.FSL_ScheduleSABatch .execute: line 30, column 1

Comment: I have resolved my 2nd error by assigning myself FSL permission sets. Thanks !